# in CSS / SASS, is it possible to calculate the color for a group of classes based on the actual class name?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to write a css sheet for future pages generated. The pages will be able to set new class names in a certain format, but I do not know the exact class name.

I want to do something like:

```
[class *= 'mykeyword'] {
  color: some_function(actual_class_name) ;
}
```

This way, for example, I can set random colors for this group of classes that carry "mykeyword" in name using a hash function.

Is this possible?

Comment: If the class name is a valid css colour then you can do this. Or simply let the scss colour variables determine this, but in this way I'd recommend naming them something around its use, not its colour. "Brand" and "link" colours being generic enough to be used more places and also changed later in a more meaningful way.

Comment: @Nathaniel, yeah, the class names won't be color related. However, just curious if the class name does contain a field of color name, how to set the color in the above case? Thanks!

Comment: Just use the same variable for the class name and the colour.